# Can I test funcion of nvidia decoder (nvdec/cuvid) on generated ffmpeg video?

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia, nvdec, lavfilters

goal: In my script I try to check if nvdec on my graphics card is available/functional.
I don't have any source video (H.264 / H.265) to use as input at this time intentionally, so I want to generate it.
It is also not necessary to use an encoder, because I do not need the output file.
I'm testing the exit code of command ffmpeg ($?).
I use nvidia-smi for check dec/enc load.

My attempt:

```
ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -c:v h264_cuvid -f lavfi -i testsrc="duration=5:size=1920x1080:rate=25" -c:v copy test.ts
```

output of my commands:

```
Input #0, lavfi, from 'testsrc=duration=5:size=1920x1080:rate=25':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, rgb24, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (h264_cuvid) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
No information about the input framerate is available. Falling back to a default value of 25fps for output stream #0:0. Use the -r option if you want a different framerate.
Output #0, null, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.65.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: wrapped_avframe, rgb24, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.119.100 wrapped_avframe
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

I triead add -t 5 before test.ts but nothing changed.
Output ts file has zero size.

If I debug the command, I expect to add it to the end "-f null - 2>/dev/null". Output file is only for debug purposes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first generate the video with a H.264 encoder and then try decoding it separately afterwards.

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i "testsrc2=duration=5:size=1920x1080:rate=25" -c:v h264 test.ts

ffmpeg  -c:v h264_cuvid -i test.ts -f null -
```

Comment: I didn't think to split it into 2 commands, I tried to have it all in one

```ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i "testsrc=duration=5:size=1920x1080:rate=25" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v h264 $INSTALL_TMP_DIR/sample_h264.ts 2>/dev/null; 

ffmpeg -c:v h264_cuvid -i $INSTALL_TMP_DIR/sample_h264.ts -f null - 2>/dev/null
echo $?```

It was necessary to add -pix_fmt yuv420p, otherwise my cuda decoder does not work (for input in rgb format).

Comment: Use testsrc2 instead. It defaults to yuv420p